# Translating inputs (and outputs) to find addresses involved in transaction?

Tags: transactions, address, script

Is there a way for me to translate the input and output scripts in a bitcoin transaction?

I am building an application that lets you query different stats from the Bitcoin-network, down the line I want it to be able to "trace addresses" as well.

I have tried to read up on Script and how a transaction works but I am a bit confused.

Since the built-in functions in bitcoin-cli (and most all block explorers) are able to find the addresses, I'm sure I should be able to parse and translate the scripts… or?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.stackexchange.com. Do you simply want to know how, in principle, to convert any Bitcoin script (in Hex say) to a standard address for each of the transaction output types for which an address is well-defined?  (If so, all the discussion of BigQuery may be a hindrance to getting an answer)

Comment: Ah thanks for the input, I agree. Just edited

Answer (score 2):

An address is just a standardized way to encode an output script. They aren't part of the Bitcoin protocol, and only a few standard scripts have an associated address. As of now these are P2PKH, P2SH, P2WPKH, P2WSH and P2TR.

I won't go into exact details on how to convert each of these scripts into an address, but I'll give helpful links.

### P2PKH (Pay to Public Key Hash)

A P2PKH output scripts looks like this:

```
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 <key_hash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

The `<key_hash>` part is a 160-bit hash (SHA-256 then RIPEMD-160) of a public key. The address always starts with a `1`. More details [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses).

### P2SH (Pay to Script Hash)

A P2SH output script looks like this:

```
OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 <script_hash> OP_EQUAL
```

The `<script_hash>` part is a 160-bit hash of a redeem script. The address always starts with a `3` and is constructed similarly to P2PKH. More details in [BIP13](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0013.mediawiki).

### P2WPKH (Pay to Witness Public Key Hash)

A P2WPKH output script looks like this:

```
OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 <key_hash>
```

As in P2PKH, `<key_hash>` is a 160-bit hash of a public key. The address always starts with `bc1q`. More details in [BIP173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki).

### P2WSH (Pay to Witness Script Hash)

A P2WSH output script looks like this:

```
OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_32 <script_hash>
```

The `<script_hash>` part is a 256-bit hash (double SHA-256) of a redeem script. As with P2WPKH the address always starts with `bc1q` and is also specified in [BIP173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki).

### P2TR (Pay to Taproot)

A P2TR output script looks like this:

```
OP_1 OP_PUSHBYTES_32 <key>
```

The `<key>` part is a [BIP340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki) public key. The address always starts with `bc1p`. More details in [BIP350](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0350.mediawiki).